# Derivative of a quadratic form where the vector is exponentiated

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis, quadratic-forms

$\newcommand{\vx}{\mathbf{x}}$
While solving a certain problem, I bumped into the following Lagrangian.
$$
\mathcal{L}(\vx, \lambda) = \frac{(e^\vx) ^\top A e^\vx}{(e^\vx)^\top B e^\vx} - \lambda ((e^\vx)^\top \mathbf{1} - 1)
$$
Here $\vx\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and $e^\vx$ means that we exponentiate each of its elements. $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier for the condition that the elements of $e^\vx$ sum up to one. I would like to solve the optimization problem and ***I am therefore interested in $\nabla_\vx \mathcal{L}(\vx, \lambda)$.***

## Attempt at the derivative

I have never bumped into a problem like this, so I am unsure how to take derivatives properly.

$$
\begin{align}
    \nabla_\vx \left[(e^\vx) ^\top A e^\vx\right]
&= (e^\vx \mathrm{I})(2 A e^\vx) = 2(e^\vx)^\top Ae^\vx \\
\nabla_\vx\left[(e^\vx) ^\top B e^\vx\right] &= 2 (e^\vx)^\top B e^\vx
\end{align}
$$
which would give
$$
\nabla_\vx \mathcal{L}(\vx, \lambda) = \frac{2((e^\vx)^\top A e^\vx)((e^\vx)^\top B e^\vx) - 2((e^\vx)^\top B e^\vx)((e^\vx)^\top A e^\vx)}{4 ((e^\vx)^\top B e^\vx)^2} - \lambda e^\vx = -\lambda e^\vx
$$
but surely this is incorrect

Comment: So $e^{\mathbf{x}}$ means $\exp(\sum_k x_k)$? Or the vector $(e^{x_1}, \dots, e^{x_d})$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\vx}{\mathbf{x}}$
I think the problem arises with how you compute $\nabla_\vx e^\vx$.

Here is what I think is the correct way to compute the derivative:
$$
\begin{align}
    \nabla_\vx \left[(e^\vx) ^\top A e^\vx\right] &= \frac{\partial e^\vx}{\partial\vx}A e^\vx + \frac{\partial A e^\vx}{\partial\vx} e^\vx \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial e^{x_1}}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial e^{x_2}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots &\frac{\partial e^{x_n}}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial e^{x_1}}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial e^{x_2}}{\partial x_2} & \cdots &\frac{\partial e^{x_n}}{\partial x_2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial e^{x_1}}{\partial x_n} & \frac{\partial e^{x_2}}{\partial x_n} & \cdots &\frac{\partial e^{x_n}}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
A e^\vx
+ \frac{\partial e^\vx}{\partial\vx}A ^\top e^\vx \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
 e^{x_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & e^{x_2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0& \cdots & e^{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
A e^\vx
+
\begin{bmatrix}
 e^{x_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & e^{x_2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0& \cdots & e^{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
A ^\top e^\vx \\
&=\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
 e^{x_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & e^{x_2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0& \cdots & e^{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
A 
+
\begin{bmatrix}
 e^{x_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & e^{x_2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0& \cdots & e^{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
A ^\top \right)e^\vx \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\h{\odot}   \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}
\def\l{\lambda} \def\p{\partial}
\def\L{{\large\cal L}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\cFp{\c{F'}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$A scalar function $\phi(z)$ and its derivative $\phi'(z)$ can be applied element-wise to a vector argument $x$ to generate vector-valued results
$$\eqalign{
f = \phi(x), \qquad f' = \phi'(x) \\
}$$
The $\c{\rm differential}$ of such an element-wise function can be written using the element-wise product $(\h),\,$ which in turn can be replaced by a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
F' &= \Diag{f'} \qiq f' = F'\o,\quad \o^TF' =  \LR{f'}^T \\
\c{df} &= f'\odot dx \;\equiv\; \c{F'\,dx} \\
\o^Tdf &= \o^TF'\,dx \,\equiv\; \LR{f'}^Tdx \\
}$$
For the exponential function, things are somewhat simplified since $\:f'(x)=f(x)=e^x$

For typing convenience, assume that $(A,B)$ are symmetric and define the scalars
$$\eqalign{
\a &= f^TAf &\qiq d\a = 2f^TA\,\c{df}
   &\,=\,2f^TA\c{F'\,dx} &\,=\,\LR{2F'Af}^Tdx \\
\b &= f^TBf &\qiq d\b = 2f^TB\,\c{df}
   &\,=\,2f^TB\c{F'\,dx} &\,=\,\LR{2F'Bf}^Tdx \\
}$$
Write the Lagrangian using the above notation, then calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\L &= \b^{-1}\a - \l\LR{\o^Tf-1} \\
d\L
 &= \fracLR{ \b\,d\a-\a\,d\b}{\b^2} \;-\; \l\LR{\o^Tdf} \\
 &= \fracLR{ 2\b F'Af-2\a F'Bf}{\b^2}^Tdx \;-\; \LR{\l f'}^Tdx \\
 &= 2\b^{-1}\BR{\cFp Af-\L\cFp Bf}^Tdx \;-\; \LR{\l\cFp \o}^Tdx \\
\grad{\L}{x}
 &= \fracLR2{f^TBf}\cdot\c{\Diag{e^x}}\cdot\BR{Af-\L Bf - \l\o} \\
}$$